# what is the maximum no. of digits which can be passed using intent in android application?

Tags: android, android-intent

i am new to the android and so i was just trying to make a simple application which takes an integer data,rather a mobile no. from one activity to the another (in both activities it is stored in the edittext). i used the following code in the sender activity-

```
done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i=new Intent(ctx,MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("number", Long.parseLong(edittext.getText().toString()));
            ctx.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

following is the receiving code in the receiver activity--

```
num=getIntent().getIntExtra("number", set_default);
    accept(num);

protected void accept(long t) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String a=(edittext.getText().toString()+t);
    clear(edittext);
    edittext.append(a);
}
private void clear(EditText edittext) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    edittext.setText("");

}
```

num is of type long.

the problem with the above code is that it is working correctly upto the 8 digits of numbers but not with 9 digit onwards.
previously i used int with num and int.parseInt with putExtra in sender activity,but changed to long after the problem, but it retains.

can anyone plz help me out with this??

Comment: An Integer can hold hold at least [ten digits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), if you are seeing problmes at 8 something else is wrong. Also what are you trying to do in `accept()` can you simply use `edittext.append(t+"");`?

Comment: long != int and are not parceled the same way. use getLongExtra if you put a long in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're still using `getIntExtra`. Use [`getLongExtra`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getLongExtra%28java.lang.String,%20long%29).

```
num=getIntent().getLongExtra("number", (long) set_default);
```

Comment: No problem! :) Don't forget to click the checkmark next to an answer if it helped you!